# Firebase Authentication is not working on Android 12, Targeting S+ requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-12

Firebase Authentication is not working on Android 12. The app crashes when the login is started and the error log in Android Studio is

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

I tried updating the dependencies but it still does not work.

As far as I understood the dependency for Firebase Auth needs to be updated.

```
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.0"
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?
How can we inform the Firebase developers about this issue, so that they can fix it ASAP?

Note: I know there are a lot of questions related to `FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE` but I need help with this one. I actually tried all those solutions they are not working.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're using the Firebase-UI library. Then are you sure you're using the latest "20.2.0" version for services auth `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0"`? Does it solve the issue?

Comment: are you using latest version of dependencies??

Comment: if you are using latest versions then try adding work manager runtime dependency too some of your third party libraries might have older version of it and starting from android S all Pending Intents must have IMMUTABLE or MUTABLE flags.

Comment: Thank You adding implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0" worked.

Answer (score 4):

Add Below line in your app gradle file,

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0"
```

Sync Project and Enjoy.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks!... But can you explain why it happens? Please

Comment: @JimmyALejandro Older versions of Firebase ui (like 8.0.0) transitively depends on a version of `play-services-auth` that targets an older API target. You can get a newer version of `play-services-auth` in your project that targets API 31+ *either* by upgrading to a newer version of Firebase UI (I would recommend this) *or* by explicitly declaring a newer version of `play-services-auth` as a dependency as described in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides updating the library, make sure you specify FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE when getting the result of a pending intent. It should look like this:

```
 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            );
```